# Why does calling "app.post" always return 307 on rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, console, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Ruby on Rails 5.  I'm in the console and would like to invoke a route.  However, I started noticing all of my invocations resulted in the same number, even for routes that don't exist ...

```
irb(main):007:0> app.post "/sesss"
=> 307
irb(main):008:0> app.post "/abc"
=> 307
```

When I try and add params to the call, I get an even stranger error ...

```
irb(main):009:0> app.post "/abc", {"param1" => "abc"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):9
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))
```

How do I invoke my route (with params) from the console?

Comment: Well, you would normally do it like: `app.post("/abc", params: {"param1": "abc"})` in Rails 4 and above

Comment: Do you know what was the fix? Feeling so clueless

Answer (score 0):

A little late here, but I believe this may be because you have this line in your config/environments files.

`config.force_ssl = true`